# Validation of input does not output correctly

Tags: jquery, html, text

I am on my way to learning Javascript. I created a form which looks like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Bitte verrate uns Deinen Namen."  id="anfrage-name"/>
       <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Und nun Deine E-Mail-Adresse..." id="anfrage-email"/>
       <textarea name="message" placeholder="...gefolgt von Deiner Nachricht an uns." rows="6" id="anfrage-kaufen"></textarea>               
       <input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Anfragen" id="anfrage-abschicken"/>
       <span id="error-message"></span>
    </form>
```

In JQuery I am going to validate the Email:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#anfrage-abschicken').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#anfragen-email').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            //no email
            $('#error-message').text('Du musst dieses Feld ausfüllen.');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            // email format right
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // wrong email format
            $('#error-message').text('Dein E-Mail-Format stimmt nicht.');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not working. How can I get this to work? Here is my [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gW377/)

Comment: "How can I get to work?" Take a train.

Comment: This comment deserves a smiley and +1 `:,D` !

Comment: Maybe it's the missing dollarsign that should have been the first character in that code ?

Comment: oh shit. you made me laugh haha. I am sorryy. Corrected it!

Comment: `e` is `undefined` in the `.click` handler. Modify it like so: `.click(function (e) { ... });`...

Comment: Note that you have a typo - in jQuery where you are trying to select the value of the email, you reference `$('#anfragen-email').val();` - the id on the email input is `anfrage-email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are requesting for `$('#anfragen-email')` and your element is called `anfrage-email`

After that, you can replace `e.preventDefault();` with `return false` to achieve the same goal (and this way it will work).

The remaining code seems to be right:

http://jsfiddle.net/gW377/3/

Answer (score 3):

When you submit a form use `onsubmit` event. It's a wrong approach to listen button `onclick` event. `onsubmit` event automatically responds to Enter key form submission:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var sEmail = $('#anfrage-email').val();

    if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
        //no email
        $('#error-message').text('Du musst dieses Feld ausfüllen.');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;    // <-- stop further validation
    }

    if (!validateEmail(sEmail)) {
        // wrong email format
        $('#error-message').text('Dein E-Mail-Format stimmt nicht.');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Also you passed event object `e` to the wrong function. So this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
    ...
```

Another mistake: your jQuery selector should be `$('#anfrage-email').val();` not `#anfragen-email`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gW377/5/

Comment: it's almost working. But when I type nothing in the email field, then it also displays 'wrong format'

Comment: @fjw http://jsfiddle.net/gW377/4/ In JS `#anfragen-email` should be `#anfrage-email`.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is also the submit button for the form.  I'd suggest starting by binding to the submit event for the form rather than the button click.  More generally, try the jQuery Validatory plugin which will do much of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of errors on you selectors

```
 var sEmail = $('#anfragen-email').val();
```

Should be:

```
 var sEmail = $('#anfrage-email').val();
```

Since you don't have an element with that id in you DOM

And you need to pass the event object `e` in the click event.

```
 $('#anfrage-abschicken').click(function(e) {
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gW377/2/)